# Automatically build number in DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a DataGridView and bind this to database.

I use the following code in the DataGridView for automatically creating a row number:

```
dgv.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value = e.RowIndex +1;
```

but the result is not ok. Please help me to build this number.

UPDATE:
Result:

```
1      ssss      mmmm
2      tttt      tttt
       rrrrr     rrrr
       tttttt    tttt
....
```

So the last two rows don't show the number.

Comment: salam. WindowsForms or Asp.NET?

Comment: It seems your method is the simplest way and works correctly

Comment: no show all number in Result auto number

Comment: Where this code be used?? i use code in dgv_RowsAdded(...). its ok??

Answer (score 2):

The `RowsAdded` event will not work for this - try adding some debugging output to your event handler and you will see that the event is fired for sets of rows, not for single rows, which is why you only get the first two values filled in.

A better place to do this is in the `DataBindingComplete` and the `DefaultValuesNeeded` events.

`DataBindingComplete` will fill in all the values on the first load and then `DefaultValuesNeeded` will fill in every new row.

DataBindingComplete:

```
void dataGridView1_DataBindingComplete(object sender, DataGridViewBindingCompleteEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (DataGridViewRow r in dataGridView1.Rows)
    {
        r.Cells["AutoGenColumn"].Value = r.Index + 1;
    }
}
```

DefaultValuesNeeded:

```
void dataGridView1_DefaultValuesNeeded(object sender, DataGridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    dataGridView1.Rows[e.Row.Index].Cells["AutoGenColumn"].Value = e.Row.Index + 1;
}
```

---

This requirement does seem a little unusual - You don't explain why you need this number but you might want to look at adding the row to your underlying dataset instead (very easy to do with a DataTable for example) or to put this into the row header as Subek suggests.

---

One last thing to note - this sort of autogenerated column is usually best done in the `CellValidating` event, for example when you and a column where you sum two other columns. That doesn't work here since your column is not based on other columns, but is worth mentioning as the general way to go.

Answer (score 0):

You can show that in header cell..

```
DataGridView gridView = sender as DataGridView;

    if (null != gridView)
    {
        foreach (DataGridViewRow r in gridView.Rows)
        {
            gridView.Rows[r.Index].HeaderCell.Value = (r.Index + 1).ToString();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is most simple , works 100% for me

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Sl. No.">
   <ItemTemplate>
       <%# Container.DataItemIndex + 1 %>
   </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

[image]

Comment: it works buddy, if your looking for something else , let me know

Answer (score 0):

This will work.

```
public Form1()
{
    ... ...
    gridView.RowStateChanged += GridView_RowStateChanged;
}

private void GridView_RowStateChanged(object sender, DataGridViewRowStateChangedEventArgs e)
{
    (sender as DataGridView).Rows[e.Row.Index].Cells[0].Value = e.Row.Index + 1;
}
```

[image]

I had tried `RowsAdded` event at the first, but it didn't work properly for rows added newly.